# Apache reverse proxy changing Content-Type

Tags: apache2, reverse-proxy

**Update 3:**

I've experimented a bit with setting ContentType for all css files to different types like text/plain, text/html and text/css in the .htaccess file of the webserver hosting Owncloud and when running `curl --head http://www.<myDomain>.com/core/css/styles.css?v=abbcfa8606670b201527db15c9717a61`
from the reverse proxy server, the changes are reflected in the Content-Type header.

However when running the same curl command directed at the reverse proxy I only get the same `Content-Type text/html; charset=UTF-8`

**Update 2:**

I've compared the http response headers when accessing the page directly and via reverse proxy and I've found that when going directly and requesting a css file the Content-Type is text/css but when going through reverse proxy it is text/html; charset=UTF-8.

Why does the proxy change Content-Type and how can I prevent it? I've tried setting `DefaultType None` in apache2.conf but doesn't make any difference.

**Update:**

In google chrome I also get variants of the error message

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://<my-server-address>/core/css/styles.css?v=f8ed568350f3f0107c10d8e06c55f727".`

If I remove the line from .htaccess

`Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"`

I no longer get the error message about strict MIME type checking but I get the same "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet" messages and also variants of:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  oc.js?v=f8ed568... :1`

The following are my http headers:

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 08 Apr 2016 20:04:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; img-src * data: blob:; font-src 'self' data:; media-src *; connect-src *
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Robots-Tag: none
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: ocirse4el2n4=0aad97s9uv1g5sclishd7sev85; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: oc_sessionPassphrase=YFrm%2BphkwzrtmgZ%2BJPnv9%2BJXZ4jYMK7TRPuHrgyoJ324CiFcGDm%2FrVITkXEjLDZXYUw%2BGLGrXe1tt8v3YZiHabYyd3Muwfq7BTcY%2FuFzVimQxYGCa682%2FDehZGG0HyRS; path=/; httponly`

I have two ubuntu servers 14.04 running apache 2.4.7, mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.22-MariaDB and php 5.5.9.

One of them is internal with no Internet access running an owncloud server and the other is facing the Internet with an apache server running a reverse proxy for the internal server to enable access to owncloud from the Internet.

The problem I'm having is that when going through the reverse proxy the webpage loads but most of the content seems to fail and the website doesn't work as expected. If I open the console I get the variants of the following error messages:

In firefox console:

```
The stylesheet <my-server-address>/core/css/jquery.ocdialog.css?v=f8ed568350f3f0107c10d8e06c55f727 was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

In google chrome console:

```
Refused to execute script from '<my-server-address>/index.php/core/js/oc.js?v=f8ed568350f3f0107c10d8e06c55f727' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Accessing owncloud webpage internally works good which is why I think that the problem is with the reverse proxy.

This is how it looks when going through the reverse proxy:

[image: This is how it looks when going through the reverse proxy]

And this is how it looks when going locally:
[image]

Also note that the button on the first picture is not responding.

Comment: [How to preserve the Content-Type header of a Tomcat HTTP response sent through an AJP connector to Apache using mod_proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399605/how-to-preserve-the-content-type-header-of-a-tomcat-http-response-sent-through-a) has an answer that indicates that you should set the default content type to "None" on Apache

Comment: [Garbled output with Apache mod_proxy](http://www.moeding.net/archives/29-Garbled-output-with-Apache-mod_proxy.html) suggests that using HTTP/1.0 without keepalive between your proxy and backend prevents this type of problem:   `SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1` and `SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out that I was missing a trailing / on the ProxyPass commands.

Previously I had written:

```
ProxyPass / http://cloud.myDomain.com
ProxyPassReverse / http://cloud.myDomain.com
```

It should be:

```
ProxyPass / http://cloud.myDomain.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://cloud.myDomain.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

If your proxy server or container adds the following header when serving the .css file, it will force some browsers such as Chrome to perform strict checking of MIME types:

```
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

Remove this header to prevent Chrome performing the MIME check.

Comment: Any idea why the problem only shows up while going through the proxy?

Comment: @Jimmy It could be the proxy adding the header.

Comment: I retrieved the http headers from visiting the page directly and from going via the reverse proxy and both set the X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff.

Comment: @Jimmy if you view the page directly does the css show "type="text/css"" or "type="text/html"" ? Is it different from proxy vs direct?

Comment: Initially it was: Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 on both direct and proxy.
I tried changing it to: Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8; text/css .css; text/javascript .js but it doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: Then it must not be set for some reason because if chrome is giving you an error saying that the mime type is still text/html that is the issue. You could either figure out how to fix the mime type or just disable the header from being sent on both the origin and proxy.

Comment: I've tried disabling the nosniff but that doesn't seem to matter either. It still complains that the MIME type is text/html and not text/css

Comment: Hmm, any sort of caching or apache not restart to apply the new header changes?

Comment: I've restarted apache between each change and used curl -I <website> to check the headers between each change which has confirmed them.

Comment: @Jimmy sorry man i dunno, the error points to strict mime types, removing the header should no longer get the browser to enforce this. :|